# Execution failed error when packages added

Tags: flutter, android-multidex

I got this exception when i added below packages.

firebase_auth: 0.3.1
  firebase_storage: 0.0.7
  firebase_database: 0.1.4
  image_picker: 0.1.5

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzdtf.class

Comment: actualy this error occured when i add firebase_auth: 0.3.1 and firebase_database: 0.1.4 together

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a problem with dependencies on different versions of Google packages. For firebase_auth there is a version 0.3.2 available, did you try that one?

Comment: Do you also have some packages added to your android project?

Comment: yes 
'firebase_auth: 0.3.1
  firebase_storage: 0.0.7
  firebase_database: 0.1.4
  image_picker: 0.1.5'

Comment: But these are flutter packages right? I was asking about android (in the gradle file).
Btw, I see that there is also a newer version of firebase_storage, did you also change that to the newest one?

Comment: I think there is some problem with auth plugin, I just downgrade auth plugin version and it's working